# How does the Firestore 500 writes/sec per collection limit work on subcollection groups?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Collections with sequentially-valued indexed fields impose a limit of 500 writes per second on that collection. How does a subcollection group affect that limit? For example, consider this data schema:

```
[collection]
    <documentId>
        + indexed field
        - index-exempt field
        [subcollection]
            <documentId>
                ...

[products]

    <productId>
        - name: string

        [sensors]

            <sensorId>
                + lastCalibrated: timestamp
```

Because `lastCalibrated` is a sequentially-valued indexed field, the 500 writes/sec collection limit comes into play. In this example, does that limit apply to each `sensors` subcollection independently or to all `sensors` subcollections in the aggregate as if they were one giant collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easiest to keep in mind that the limit comes from the need to update indexes. With that knowledge answering a question like yours becomes a lot easier.

If you want to perform a collection-group query across  all the `sensors` subcollections, then you will need to have have an index across those collections. At that point those collections will be subject to the same 500 writes/sec limit.

Comment: Is the write limit applied to those subcollections in the aggregate, as if they were one collection?

Comment: Yes. The index for a Collection Group Query spans all collections in that group. Since the write limit comes from having to update the indexes, it also spans all subcollections  in that case.